# legend at the top position is not showing

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, legend

Christmas Greetings!, Please help in drawing the legends on the basis of line type using R:

```
ggplot(mkt_liq, aes(x = Timestamp)) + geom_line(aes(y = CG), colour="green",linetype = "solid",size=1,alpha = 1,show_guide = TRUE) +  
geom_line(aes(y = FS), colour = "red",linetype = "dotdash",size=1,show_guide = TRUE) +   geom_line(aes(y = MAN), colour = "black",linetype = "dotted",size=1,show_guide = TRUE)+   
geom_line(aes(y = INFRA), colour = "blue",linetype = "longdash",size=1,show_guide = TRUE)+ ylab(label="Sectors") +   xlab("Time")+ theme(legend.position="top")
```

The data set looks like:

```
Timestamp   CG          FS            MAN        INFRA
9:30:00     0.680211107 0.11651278  4.792954196 0.643453697
10:00:00    0.486717157 0.106090614 2.996018087 0.387472797
10:30:00    0.458210851 0.103258739 2.802459194 0.360074724
11:00:00    0.450227036 0.103551557 2.706885909 0.365001632
```

Comment: add a reproducible example...we don't have access to your dataset so we can't test your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use reshape and melt your variables:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(1234)
n <- 100
sdate <- as.POSIXct("2015-11-11 00:00:00",tz="UCT")
edate <- as.POSIXct("2015-11-11 23:59:59",tz="UCT")

mkt_liq <- data.frame(
  Timestamp =  as.POSIXct(runif(n,sdate,edate),tz="UCT",origin="1970-01-01"),
  CG = 0.5 + rnorm(n,0,0.15),
  FS = 0.1 + rnorm(n,0,0.01),
  MAN = 2.8 + rnorm(n,0,0.5),
  INFRA = 0.4 + rnorm(n,0,0.05)
)

# The wrong way
ggplot(mkt_liq, aes(x = Timestamp)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = CG), colour="green",linetype = "solid",size=1) +  
  geom_line(aes(y = FS), colour = "red",linetype = "dotdash",size=1) +   
  geom_line(aes(y = MAN), colour = "black",linetype = "dotted",size=1)+   
  geom_line(aes(y = INFRA), colour = "blue",linetype = "longdash",size=1)+ 
  ylab(label="Sectors") +   
  xlab("Time")+ 
  theme(legend.position="top")
```

Yields this:

[image]

But what you really want is this:

```
# The right way
mdf <- melt(mkt_liq,id=c("Timestamp"),variable.name="Sector" )

clrs <- c("CG"="green","FS"="red","MAN"="black","INFRA"="blue")
ltyp <- c("CG"="solid","FS"="dotdash","MAN"="dotted","INFRA"="longdash")

ggplot(mdf, aes(x = Timestamp,y=value,color=Sector,linetype=Sector)) + 
  geom_line(size=1)+
  ylab(label="Sectors") +   
  xlab("Time")+ 
  scale_color_manual( values=clrs )+
  scale_linetype_manual( values=ltyp )+
  theme(legend.position="top")
```

yields this:
[image]

Done

## Update:

Made better data and added variable and names to more flexibly indicate the colors and linetypes.

Comment: ...Many thanks for the kind help. God bless you on this auspicious day. :)